# How to display the datas in console from http get request in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, get, httprequest

I am working on HTTP GET and POST Request/Response.
It's working fine with POST, but stuck up with GET method..

In my console, I am getting a data as 379 bytes. But, I need to display the whole data(machine readable format) in my console. Afterwards, I will convert it into JSON Format.

Commented lines are POST Method.

Here is my code..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&Username=%@&Password=%@",@"username", @"password"];
//    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
//    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.abcde.com/xyz/login.aspx"]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
//    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type" ];
//    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if(conn)
    {
        NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Connection Not Succeeded");
    }

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert 1" message:@"Data Received" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:Nil, nil];
    [alert show];

}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert 2" message:@"Error Occurred" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:Nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    NSLog(@"Error Description is here: %@", error.description);
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert 3" message:@"Finished Loading" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:Nil, nil];
    [alert show];
//    NSLog(@"Displaying the Datas Received %@",);

}
```

Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: GET request has size limit. Why do you want to use GET instead of POST ?

Comment: To get the response back..I need to see those datas in my console

Comment: POST request also has response. Any misunderstanding in HTTP request ?

Comment: In GET method, we will get response back right? I need to display those responses in my console..got it?

Comment: in GET & POST method, you can get response back.

Comment: I know, in both method we can get response back..I need to display those response (in form of datas) in my console

Comment: put this line `NSLog(@"Displaying the Datas Received %@",data);` in your `-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data` delegate method

Comment: how about `NSLog` the POST response in console? It should be possible.

Comment: @PratyushaTerli: How can I convert those datas into readable format?

Comment: I have posted the answer check if it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"Displaying the Datas Received %@",data);
    NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Displaying the Datas Received In Readable Format %@",strResult);
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert 1" message:@"Data Received" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:Nil, nil];
    [alert show];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ASI HTTP library or AFHTTPClient available on git or use can use

below is the code to make a post request

```
+(NSData *)postDataToUrl:(NSString*)urlString:(NSString*)jsonString
{
    NSData* responseData = nil;
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    responseData = [NSMutableData data] ;
    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *bodydata=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"data=%@",jsonString];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSData *req=[NSData dataWithBytes:[bodydata UTF8String] length:[bodydata length]];
    [request setHTTPBody:req];
    NSURLResponse* response;
    NSError* error = nil;
    responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request   returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"the final output is:%@",responseString);

    return responseData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case your data is too long, then you will recieve data in chunks and delegate `didRecieveData:` will be called automatically multiple times. So you need to append all the data you recieve in response into a `NSMutableData`.
Create a `NSMutableData` object and append data in it as you recieve data in `didRecieveData:` delegate.

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [myData appendData:data];
}
```

finaly when your request is completed then convert that data into string.

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    NSString * stringData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert 3" message:@"Finished Loading" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:Nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    NSLog(@"Displaying the Datas Received %@", stringData);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to have finished delegate method for URL request! The code should look like

```
@interface YourClass : UIViewController <NSURLConnectionDataDelegate> {
        NSMutableData *__downloadingData;
}   

//YourClass Delegation Handlers
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

    if (!__downloadingData)
        __downloadingData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:0];

    [__downloadingData appendData:data];
    //
//        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert 1" message:@"Data Received" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:Nil, nil];
//    [alert show];

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSLog(@"Data Received %@",__downloadingData);
    NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:__downloadingData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Data Received In Readable Format %@",strResult);


}
```